# How can I chain together regular expression substitutions

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I am trying to write a command that changes author lists of the form

```
R. L. Rivest, A. Shamir, and L. Adleman
```

Into one nice for BibTeX, namely:

```
Rivest, R. L. and
Shamir, A. and
Adleman, L
```

I have figured out how to do it in two commands:

```
" This command will split the names so they are one per line, noting that
" sometimes the author list may end in ', and' or 'and ' or just ', '
command! -range=% Namesplit <line1>,<line2>s/,\? and \|, \|$/,\r/g

" This command expects one name per line. It finds all of the first
" and middle names, followed by the last name and a comma. It then
" rearranges the last name first, appends an and after each author,
" and lastly (piped) deletes the last trailing 'and'
command! -range=% Lnfn <line1>,<line2>s/\(\%([^, ]\+ \)\+\)\([^, ]\+\),\|$/\2, \1and/e | <line1>,<line2>s/\_.*\zsand//g
```

This is kind of messy, but it's challenging whenever you're dealing with names in LaTeX, which may contain things like `\'{e}`, so the name regexp has to be very general. I tried to pipe these through together, but it didn't work when the names got split into multiple lines.

Comment: DOUBTS : [[D1]] Does your 2 Command Method work on the very last line , which will not have the following "and" ? [[D2]] Can you put these two into a function & call that function with 1 Command ?

Comment: I don't think this is what you're looking for, but if you add [`-bar`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-bar) to your first definition (so it starts `command! -bar -range=% Namesplit...`) then you can chain your two commands with a pipe character: `:Namesplit | Lnfn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command works on a single line. The command itself would need some refinement but it works. You may adapt it into a range function or a range command.

```
s/,\? and \|, \|$/,/g | s/\(.\{-}\) \(\S\+\(,\|$\)\)/\2 \1 and/g | s/ and$// | s/ and/ and\r/g
```

And a multiline command:

```
'<,'>s/\n/,/g | s/,\? and \|, \|,$/,/g | s/\(.\{-}\) \(\S\+\(,\|$\)\)/\2 \1 and/g | s/ and$// | s/ and/ and\r/g
```

Comment: Your multiple line version only provides a range to the first command in the sequence.

Comment: Yes because it joins all lines and then, the other commands operate on one line ; the last one adds carriage return.

Comment: This works in most cases. What it won't work for are names like `de la Fuente`, but determining the last name in any case is not well-suited for a regular expression.

To clarify a bit: The first pipe is the same as what I asked in the question and ensures each name ends with a comma. The second
`/\(.\{-}\) \(\S\+\(,\|$\)\)/`
matches as few characters as possible before a space (to get the last name), then matches the rest of the characters (until a comma or end of line).

The third just deletes the extra `and` at the last author, and the fourth adds newlines.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use vim for this. I would use an awk script.

Here's the first iteration as a one-liner:

```
:'<,'>!awk 'BEGIN {RS=","} { f=split($0, name_arr, " "); print name_arr[f] ", " name_arr[1] " and"}'
```

But if you want to do this right (trim the word `and`, support first names that're more than 1 word long, not print out the trailing `and`) then you should write an awk script, save it in a file, and invoke it like so:

```
:'<,'>!awk -f names.awk
```

---

Here's my attempt at writing your awk script for you.

```
BEGIN {RS=","}
function format_name(str) {
  number_of_fields = split($0, name_arr, " ");
  first_name = ""
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_fields; i++) {first_name += name_arr[i]}
  last_name = name_arr[number_of_fields]
}
/and/ {
  print format_name(sub(/and /, ""))
  next
}
{ print format_name($0) " and" }
```

Test it, fix it if it doesn't work, and then edit this answer (or comment on it and I'll edit it if you don't have enough reputation)